100 green eyed prisoner puzzle: Why can't the prisoners figure it out on their own?
Refering to the 100 green eyed prisoner puzzle from the TED-Ed video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98TQv5IAtY8:
Summary from a different question:
Imagine an island where 100 people,all perfect logicians,are imprisoned by a mad dictator.There's no escape,except for one strange rule. Any prisoner can approach the guards at night and ask to leave. If they have green eyes, they'll be released. If not, they'll be tossed into the volcano. As it happens, all 100 prisoners have green eyes, but they've lived there since birth, and the dictator has ensured they can't learn their own eye color. There are no reflective surfaces, all water is in opaque containers, and most importantly, they're not allowed to communicate among themselves. Though they do see each other during each morning's head count. Nevertheless, they all know no one would ever risk trying to leave without absolute certainty of success.
On a morning, they are provided the information that "At least one of you has green eyes." causing that on the hundredth morning after the sentence all the prisoners are gone.
My question:
Why can't the prisoners figure this out on their own? Why do they need to be told this information at all?
If there are at least 3 green eyes prisoners, every prisoner knows that every prisoner knows that there is at least one prisoner with green eyes.
If they all were put into prison the same day, knew that everyone present is a perfect logician and wants to leave, and saw that everyone sees at least one other prisoner with green eyes, why couldn't they just start the process immediately?

Here is another duplicate.  For intuition, I suggest thinking through the case in which there are only $2$ prisoners.
